# When using Selectize in multiple columns, can drop down list update dynamically with current selections?

Tags: jquery, datatables, shiny, selectize.js, dt

I'm using Selectize filter with Shiny DT. Take [the example here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/008-filter.html), if we select the `Petal.Length` as 1.3 - 4.3, the only available species are `setosa` and `versicolor`. However the `Species` drop down list always have the full list, thus if you select `virginica` there will be no matches.

I'm wondering if it is possible the drop down list be updated by current selections, so the options not available will not appear in list. I checked Selectize briefly but didn't find answer.

Comment: Did you try this: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/27541/update-select-filters?

Comment: This looks like just what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The behavior of that example is exactly what I want. Though it is datatables select api, not Selectize. So if there are a lot of categories, Selectize can be more helpful with partial matching for input, but the regular select can only scroll in all options manually. I'm also not sure how this can be applied to Shiny DT.